# Assumptions for FourierSeries

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I want to calculate the Fourier series of the following function.

$u(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{lc}0, & -\frac{T}{2} \leqslant t<-\frac{\tau}{2} \\ h, & -\frac{\tau}{2} \leqslant t<\frac{\tau}{2} \\ 0, & \frac{\tau}{2} \leqslant t<\frac{T}{2}\end{array}\right.$

The result should be

$u(t)=\frac{h \tau}{T}+\frac{h}{\pi} \sum_{\substack{n=-\infty \\ n \neq 0}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sin \frac{n \pi \tau}{T} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2 n \pi t}{T} \mathrm{i}}$

Before calculation, the parameters have been assumed to be positive real numbers.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
$Assumptions = 
  n \[Element] Integers && n >= 0 && T > 0 && \[Tau] > 0 && 
   T > \[Tau] && h > 0;
u[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, -T/2 <= t < -\[Tau]/2}, {h, -\[Tau]/2 <= 
      t < \[Tau]/2}, {0, \[Tau]/2 <= t < T/2}}];
sol = FourierSeries[u[t], t, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi/T}]
```

> $\left(\left[\begin{array}{ll}\frac{h \tau}{\text { Abs }[T]} & \tau>0 \& \& \tau<A b s[T] \\ h & \tau>0 \& \& \text { Abs }[T]>0 \& \& \tau \geq A b s[T] \\ 0 & \text { True }\end{array}\right)+\right.$....(Too complicated)

However, the assumption doesn't seem to work for the calculation of Fourier series. The results of Fourier series are still very complex. Can the results be simplified under the assumption of positive real numbers of these parameters? How to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `$Assumptions=...` and try

```
sol = FourierSeries[u[t], t, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi/T}] // Simplify[#, {h > 0, T > \[Tau] > 0}] &    
sol // ExpToTrig // ComplexExpand // Simplify
    (*(h (6 \[Pi] \[Tau] - 2 T Sin[(\[Pi] (6 t - 3 \[Tau]))/T] - 
   3 T Sin[(\[Pi] (4 t - 2 \[Tau]))/T] - 
   6 T Sin[(\[Pi] (2 t - \[Tau]))/T] + 
   6 T Sin[(\[Pi] (2 t + \[Tau]))/T] + 
   3 T Sin[(2 \[Pi] (2 t + \[Tau]))/T] + 
   2 T Sin[(3 \[Pi] (2 t + \[Tau]))/T]))/(6 \[Pi] T)*)
```

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

sometimes global `$Assumptions` are not used for some reason.  However, using them directly in the call itself does work:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
assume = T > 0 && tau > 0 && T > tau && h > 0;
u[t_] := Piecewise[{{0, -T/2 <= t < -tau/2}, {h, -tau/2 <= t < 
     tau/2}, {0, tau/2 <= t < T/2}}]

sol = FourierSeries[u[t], t, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi/T}, 
  Assumptions -> assume]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To convert to trig do

```
ExpToTrig[sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The result is perfect! Thank you!